# Add a class in a JSP facet?

Tags: java, jsp, facet

I can't  achieve to add a class in a facet :

```
<p:dataTable>
    <f:facet name="footer" class="myClass">
        <p>outch!</p>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

render :

```
<div class="ui-datatable-footer ui-widget-header ui-corner-bottom">
    <p>outch!</p>
</div>
```

perhaps it's not possible, but what can be the alternative to put myClass in the DIV class ?

Many thanks to any help ;-)

françois

Edit :

OK : facet have no attribut, so I'll try an other approch.
thks all.

Comment: The facet tag does not have a class attribute. Are you trying to populate the list from a backing (managed) bean or what?

Comment: why not setting the `class` attribute of its child, in this case `p`?

Comment: When you work with a CSS framework, the goal is to add classes to your elements (div, a, p, etc.), and not to override tons of Primefaces classes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The facet tag does not have a class attribute as you can see in tag library documentation  [f:facet](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/facet.html)

If you want to override the default CSS for Primefaces datatable footer you can check this [override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Comment: Please add some explaination to your link-only answer, i.e. some relevant information of the linked source.

Comment: OK : facet tag does not have a class attribute. When you work with a CSS framework, the is to add classes to your elemnts, and not to override tons of Primefaces classes. So : no way to add a class near Primefaces  ones?

Comment: I think it's not possible in this case. Only if primefaces tags have a `styleClass` attribute.